# При использование ProductList-a получаю ошибку "Couldn't build JSON"

Tags: json, яндекс-острова

Использую в Яндекс Острове Тип обновляемых данных `"ProductList"`, на [форме](http://interactive-answers.webmaster.yandex.ru/examples/?id=477415f4-c867-4068-93f4-fc68b6af6199&query=) имею несколько выпадающих списков. При выборке неправильных размеров результат должен быть: "`По заданным критериям нет результатов"`.

В большинстве случаев все выводит нормально, но бывают случаи когда `Json` не парсит, например, если в [форме](http://interactive-answers.webmaster.yandex.ru/examples/?id=477415f4-c867-4068-93f4-fc68b6af6199&query=) выбрать только во 2-ой выпадающий список (*Профиль*) размер *10,5* выдает другую ошибку:

```
Кажется, что-то пошло не так
Не удается получить результаты с сайта ....
```

Если выбрать другой размер, например *6.5*, то все правильно возвращает

```
"По заданным критериям нет результатов"
```

Со стороны сервера я возвращаю один и тот же html в случае если нет результатов:

```
<div itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ItemList'>
  <link itemprop='url' href='example.ru'/>   
  <span itemprop='numberOfElements'>0</span>
</div>
```

Почему-то реагирует по разному, я имею в виду парсинг JSON-a. Какие-нибудь предложение как можно решить проблему? Может другой HTML нужен возвращать, когда нет результатов?

Comment: Ваши формы недоступны... А стоп, 2014 год...